# Is there a term for errors by native speakers?

Tags: terminology, errors

I'm not talking about dialectal terms. Say that someone consistently uses a dialect of English fluently but, for whatever reason, says something that native speakers wouldn't normally say.

This came to my mind when (of all things) I was watching [a video of Markiplier](https://youtu.be/DWe0RZaBvVk?t=654) and he said this:

> AH! I didn't say shoot yourself! ...Did you just **shot** yourself?!

Thanks for any assistance, and sorry if I somehow overlooked a pre-existing question!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no universally accepted term. How you describe such a thing depends on context.

For instance, in second language acquisition people differentiate between **error** and **mistake** the first being a sign of a systematic lack of competence in a particular  area whereas the latter is just an accident that does not signify anything about the speaker's ability to produce a given form.

In other contexts, people talk about **slips of the tongue** to indicate the accidental nature of these incidents. (This would probably describe your example). However, it turns out that these 'slips' can be quite systematic among native speakers, particularly when it comes to agreement and tense. Some terms to describe these things include **zeugma** or **anakoluthon** (although the latter is not used in English).

Mistakes/slips also often occur where there are similar expressions that get blended in the speaker's/hearer's mind. There's a whole  traditional classification of such misspoken expressions that includes terms like **malapropism**, **spooonersim**,  **eggcorn**, **mondegreen**, or the recently coined  **crash blossom**. All of these have detailed Wikipedia entries if you want to find out more.

Answer (score 1):

[Cacography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cacography) is deliberate misspelling intended to convey humorous sense or just exaggerating someone's illiteracy.

See also [Sensational spelling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensational_spelling). It has similar effect, but using literate, but rare or dialectal spelling of a word or phrase.

<sub>(sorry for essentially copy-pasting [my own answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/99/27) at ELL.SE)</sub>